# Setup IIS7 with SSRS running

Tags: iis, reporting-services, iis-7, ssrs-2008-r2

In my server I have SSRS already running.
http://localserver/ReportServer/

Is it possible to setup a virtual directory browsing using IIS running concurrently ?

http://localserver/IISFolder/

Tried login to my IIS and all the services are running. Try to browse website using port 80 but failed. Is SSRS conflicting with the existing IIS settings ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely possible - I have it working fine. When you say it fails, what happens exactly? And can you still access http://localserver/ReportServer/ ok?

Comment: Yes, I can access localserver/ReportServer.

Figure out the issue. In IIS7 and SSRS, there's no physical folder on in my inet/wwwroot folder. It won't work if I create anything here. I just need to create a virtualdirectory under the default IIS7.0 website which redirected to SSRS. It seems to work after that ...

Comment: Now, need to find a way to create a link in my SSRS interface so that user can access the virtualdirectory link.